# How to correctly import a function, returning Promise? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-modules

there's a promise-returning function **fileToArray()**. It successfully works in its original js file. But if i export it and import in another file, it doesn't: i receive error.
**Code in orig file:**

```html
function fileToArray(Object) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(Object.file),
            crlfDelay: Infinity
        });
        rl.on('line', line => Object.array.push(line));
        rl.on('close', () => resolve(Object.array));
        rl.on('error', err => reject(err))
    });
}

fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
//^^ works, returns full array

module.exports = fileToArray; //export line
```

**there's code where i import it:**

```html
const fileToArray = require('./myLib');
fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
```

and **error after execution:**

```html
fileToArray({file:"./maleNames.txt",array:[]}).then(lines => console.log(lines));
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: module.exports = fileToArray; remove this line and add exports.fileToArray in your first line. let try this

Comment: @AsZik no result, same error ((

Comment: Is that function working in same file

Comment: @AsZik see answer)) export was notOK

Answer (score 1):

i changed construction of import and export. Error fixed

1. Export **module.exports.fta = fileToArray;**
2. Import **let myLib = require('./myLib');**
   ...then used **myLib.fta()**